# appcompat_v7 doesn't have bin

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I created Android project in Eclipse it throw Error! In appcompat_v7 does not exist "bin" folder.

```html
[2014-12-22 13:21:48 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Eclipse Prjects\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2014-12-22 13:21:48 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Eclipse Prjects\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2014-12-22 13:38:39 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Eclipse Prjects\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2014-12-22 13:38:39 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Eclipse Prjects\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2014-12-22 13:38:42 - Hello] C:\Eclipse Prjects\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2014-12-22 13:38:42 - Hello] 
[2014-12-22 13:38:42 - Hello] C:\Eclipse Prjects\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-12-22 13:38:42 - Hello] 
[2014-12-22 13:38:42 - Hello] C:\Eclipse Prjects\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-12-22 13:38:42 - Hello] 

and so on
```

What do?

Comment: You need to set the appcompat_v7's target sdk to the highest version.

Answer (score 0):

Remove appcompat_v7 from project properties and edit the style.xml files

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="what ever the error is ">
```

replace it with this style or any other you want

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```